# How can I configure ActionMailer to conditionally send emails in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, config, actionmailer

I have ActionMailer configured to send emails through gmail in development mode.

config/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: ENV["MY_DOMAIN"] }
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: ENV["MY_DOMAIN"],
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["MY_USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["MY_PASSWORD"]
}
```

I have this set up so my designer can trigger and send test html emails to a designated address for testing in a variety of browsers / devices.

However, in development mode, I'd like to block all outgoing emails that are not being sent to that one designated email address.

I'm looking for something like:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = target_is_designated_email_address?
```

... but I need someway to inspect the Mail instance, to ensure that it's being sent to the correct address.

any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Mail interceptors in the mail gem that ActionMailer uses. You can find out more about them in this [railscast on ActionMailer](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3?view=asciicast).

The relevant part straight from the railscast:

Create a class to redirect mail.

```
class DevelopmentMailInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    message.subject = "[#{message.to}] #{message.subject}"
    message.to = "eifion@asciicasts.com"
  end
end
```

Register the interceptor in development mode only:

```
Mail.register_interceptor(DevelopmentMailInterceptor) if Rails.env.development?
```

Then it will just replace the subject line with "[youremail@blahbalh.com] Some subject" and redirect the message to whomever you want.